# Problema al cambiar de imagen en carousel bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un carousel con sus respectivas imagenes(3), al momento de dar click para cambiar a la otra imagen no se cambia ( estoy usando bootstrap 4 ).

```
    <!--Carousel-->
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="image/GG.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h5>Prueba1</h5>
    <p>La Mejor Partida</p>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="image/Netflix.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h5>...</h5>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="image/Mira papa.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h5>...</h5>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Algún error en consola?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno de los problemas más comunes es como están ordenados los archivos , como aclaración el orden sería así 
Primero va el archivo base de css que tiene bootstrap, el archivo de jquery, el archivo popper,js y por ultimo el archivo js de bootstrap, así:

```
   <!---Esta etiqueta va en el head, el css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--el resto de etiquetas van abajo en el body-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Cabe declarar que estos son cdns nada mas, pero cuando descargas los archivos , siempre es bueno usar los archivos sin el `.min`,¿Por que?, porque los archivos sin `.min` sirven para el desarrollo y te detallan mejor los errores en caso de que tengas algo mal, cuando descargues los archivos trata de poner jquery para desarrollo que está [acá](https://jquery.com/download/) y cuando vallas a subir el proyecto a producción , descargas el que dice ***production*** que es el que está minificado, y lo mismo con los de bootstrap , usaras para desarrollo en `bootstrap.js` y para produccion el `bootstrap.min.js`.Todo esto como aclaración:
Te dejo la solución aca para que veas como funciona:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Carousel-->
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(137).jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Prueba1</h5>
        <p>La Mejor Partida</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(141).jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>...</h5>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(137).jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>...</h5>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Saludos.